# Align headers with text

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/B8e8A/

I have the headers with `width: 50%;` and a `span` inside the `h2` tags to help me achieve this.

I am looking to make it so the heading is left aligned to the text, so that the header bars will be of different size, yet the bars will still stretch to the left of the screen.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the following CSS:

**Changes: Removed width:50%**

```
h2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF8C00;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px 30px 15px 0;
    /*--width:50%*/
}
```

**Changes: Float right to left, text-align right to left, added nowrap**

```
h2 span {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B8e8A/1/

Comment: Just...just...I can see why you have 10.9k.  Thanks!

Comment: @Splatter glad I can help. Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Hmm, it looked like it worked, but now I look at it again, it doesn't do it right.  The text stays flush to the left of the screen, where it should stay flush with the body of text below.

Comment: @Splatter I'm not following could you elaborate?

Comment: Exactly!  Thank you.  It doesnt work in pixels, but I think it's the best solution.